# What is making this local connection to my Azure container?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core, azure-container-service

I have a server running in a Docker container on Azure Container Services.  I just looked at its log and found the following, approximately 12 seconds after the server started:

> Client connected: 10.92.0.24:53403

First off, nothing is configured to listen on port 53403 in the first place, so how is this even connecting?  Second, why is the connection coming from a private, local IP block?  Is it Azure doing something?  Docker weirdness?

For context, the log line was produced by the following C# code:

```
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, NetworkInfo.TCP_PORT);
server.Start();
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Server started.");
using var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: Client connected: {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
```

There should not be any connections logged, because I'm testing some experimental software and I have the only client and the only knowledge of where the server is, and I haven't started it yet.  But something is connecting to it, and the IP address suggests that "the call is coming from inside the house."  I'd sure like to know why!

Comment: @Austin Define "connected to"?  There's an Azure private repository that holds my image, which I then built a container group to instantiate.  But the server inside the container isn't doing anything to interact with the repo.  It's just sitting there waiting for a connection.

Comment: Do you only log the first connection, or is it possible that it repeats given enough time? Maybe it's a health check or readiness probe?

Comment: @mherzig Logging shows this connection repeats every few seconds.

Comment: For most logs, this is the client's IP address and port **10.92.0.24:53403**. The address **10.92.0.24** is an RFC 1918 address which means it is coming from your VNET or an Azure service connected to your VNET. Review your subnets and find **10.92.0.0**. You will then know which subnet. There are more complicated scenarios such as load balancer proxy addresses, Health Checks, etc. Your question does not include enough information to answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley There is no subnet.  This is a "simplest possible setup" for testing purposes only.  The listener is only listening on a nonstandard port number that nothing but my client ought to know exists, so this isn't some routine health check pinging port 80.  Something very strange is going on here!